# Vim: Perl-Filter to find duplicates of \label in a LaTeX file

Tags: perl, vim

I need a vim filter, finding duplicates (or more) of `\labels{foo}` in my .tex file.

I tried with `__DATA__` to learn. How to achieve this?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my %seen;
while ( <DATA> ) {
      if(/\\label\{([^}]+)\}/){
          $seen{$1}++;
#         print Dumper(%seen); 
#         print $seen{'2'};
          print "$_\n" for keys %seen;
}

__DATA__
        \label{fig:foo}
        \label{fig:bar}
        \label{fig:foo1}
        \label{fig:bar1}
        \label{fig:foo2}
        \label{fig:bar2}
        \label{fig:foo}
```

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: It's not clear what output you want, or what problem you are having.

Comment: I need to print out the duplicates of the picture `\label{foo}` to correct them. LaTeX cannot refer to a label `foo`, if it is doubled.

Comment: *"I need a vim filter, finding duplicates"* : @MarekStepanek If you are writing a vim filter shouldn't you read from STDIN instead of from DATA?

Comment: Your script is missing an ending `}` for the if statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To print the duplicates you can use:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my %seen;
while ( <DATA> ) {
    if(/\\label\{([^}]+)\}/){
        $seen{$1}++;
    }
}
for my $key (keys %seen) {
    print "$key\n" if $seen{$key} > 1;
}

__DATA__
        \label{fig:foo}
        \label{fig:bar}
        \label{fig:foo1}
        \label{fig:bar1}
        \label{fig:foo2}
        \label{fig:bar2}
        \label{fig:foo}
```

**Output**:

```
fig:foo
```

Comment: Thank you Håkon, great help. My problem was a beginner problem: did not know how to access the `key` of the hash `%seen`. Just for people coming here, how to start this filter in `Vim`: in the script remove the `DATA` and issue in vim: `:%!duplicate_labels.pl` or what ever name of your script.